# What does this schematic do, simple MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, resistors, attiny

I copied a part of a schematic from another project, I put it into a simulator and it seems like it does nothing. This is for a negotiation "protocol" where you tell a 18V battery that you are about to put it into heavy load.
[image]

This schematic should work, but it does not work in the simulator. My guess is that IC DP is a Attiny85 IO pin and BAT DP goes directly into the magic battery control. So this whole thing is just to switch 18V on BAT DP. But in my [simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgosgCgAzEbBFEFBQptNjr8aJDEgoGbDKzAo8bACxVJ07Nn6DYIsONlVinFHJAzpVcmGmmoFmEgBqAewA2AFwCGAcwCmtAO5aQO8MSs-nQ%20etq6eNLBtABOAUGcYIHghFTy8PCx8SnyySh6FjIYGd6%20-mHgklBZFWAyMr75DemZoZF%20nNjc0XFd4VzyqRZgJb3cYEN9vlT5rWISUmztCtVtZotSZkMhS1tUUxNppRVN2ac7SaynK%20e0rgO7D1M7U5isr%2010AEpMLDycchmvBmBiogksAlothSIEIzVBpDYaVg8DIhA47AsEk6tCAA) it's constanly "on".

- [Q6 Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1806082136_Diodes-Incorporated-ZVP4525ZTA_C155347.pdf)
- [Q7 Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_PJ-Pingjingsemi-PJM138NSA_C411713.pdf)
- [Attiny85 Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf)
- No information on the battery

So I am confused:

1. the schematic simply does not work
2. I made a mistake in the simulation
3. I simply don't understand what this does

Comment: *BAT DP is constantly on* That makes perfect sense to me and as shown, is what I expect from that circuit. Think: what is needed to make BAT DP go low???? Can BAT DP go low in this schematic? You have fallen into the trap of simulating a circuit that only works when connected to other circuits. The complete working circuit needs more parts, parts that you have left out.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I see, but I don't have the missing parts. There is no available documentation. Maybe a better question would have been if this circut can work with any kind of other circut.

Comment: I will repeat my main question then: *what is needed to make BAT DP go low?* and refine it: **CAN** BATDP even go low in your circuit? I see some resistors connecting BAT DP to VCC....

Comment: You need a load to ground to pull BATDP low when the FET is off. Try eg 100k from BATDP to ground. Report back.

Comment: @Stackoverflowsuperbad - Hi, I've rolled-back the deletion of the schematic since, without that, the rest of the question / answers / comments make less sense. If you have a valid reason to remove information, I recommend you either raise a topic in Meta for discussion or flag your question and explain your reasons to a moderator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation works fine, the issue comes from the output of the circuit (BAT DP) in which there is no current flow so BAT DP is doomed to stay at the voltage provided by VCC no matter the status of your input (IC DP). But it is difficult to do the right simulation if you don't know how behaves BAT DP on the battery side, if this schematic is important for your project you should really focus on where you can find additional information regarding the battery.
What I suspect is that there should have a current sensing unit on the battery side:

- When your input is OFF, the current that can be read through BAT DP is the current that goes through R16 and R17.
- When IC DP is ON, the current that can be read through BAT DP is the current that goes through R16 and R17 plus the current that goes through R13 since Q6 is activated.

You can observe this by adding a 1 Ohm resistor between BAT DP and the ground and then by plotting the current that goes through this element.

Comment: As R13 is 10k your 1 Ohm will achieve only a 'ripple. Even a 100k load will give a FET_off Vout of about  Vcc/16 and Von of about Vcc x 9/10 - which is probably OK for demo purposes.